# Why am I getting the output of zero when scanning the file for a word?

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file inputted by the user then print the number of occurrences of a word also inputted by the user, even though there is multiple instances of a word I still get zero and I am unsure why.

```
try { 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the filename: ");
        String sfile = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
        String wordname = scan.next();
        FileReader fin = new FileReader(sfile);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(sfile);



        int count = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String c = scanner.next();
            if (c.equalsIgnoreCase(wordname)) {
            count++;
        }


    }     System.out.println(count);
    scan.close();
    fin.close();
    scanner.close();
        }
```

Comment: For further reading about file IO you can look at the [Java tutorial on this subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the FileReader object into your Scanner, at the moment you're passing it a String

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fin);
```

Also make sure that your file is in the root directory of your project.

```
Please enter the filename: 
hi.txt
Please enter a word: 
lol
2
```

File content:

```
lol
lol
```